# To "view" or to "if" new functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Basicly I've built a booking system in CodeIgniter. It works fine and all, and now I'm in the mood for trying to expand it's useage to also hold part time schedules for employees. The functionality is quite similiar, and the "language" to make the right text is already fixed. The part I'm thinking about now regards to how to add new functions and hide redundant functions already in place visually.

The biggest difference will basicly be a big button to sign for time, instead of inputing name and contact info, because everyone has a user account.

The choise I'm standing infront of is either:

1. Set in (a lot) of `if`s inside the currently existing views to show form elements and the like based on if it's for regular bookings or part time.
2. Create unique views in cases the content needs to be changed. Instead of `if`ing, I simply copy the content and change accordingly.

The advantage of using `if`s are in the cases when small changes are made. The advantage of using different views are that I seperate them more clearly, but might need to change content more than once.

Apparently it all comes down to how much need to be changed, but I'd like to have some feedback from you guys regarding which approach feels most logical, or if you got an even better one.

**Example 1:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

would be

```
<? if (get_calendar('business') != 'part_time'): ?>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<? endif; ?>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Would simply have another view file used without that content.

Answer (score 0):

If stmts for elements in your view will rapidly become a tangled mess you can't maintain.

Consider building your form elements using the Codeigniter Form helper, with your conditions there, and then iterating over the array of elements to display.

This separates your php logic from the html itself & I think you'll find it much easier going forward

Comment: So you mean to change it conditionally through php? I usually just use `from_dropdown()` and have the rest in pure html because I find it easier to maintain. Besides, I'm not sure if I want to have any html at all in my controllers.

Comment: you don't need to do it on the controller: you build it at the top of your view, iterate inside your html down below. In other words, just separate all your messy conditional logic from your html, so you are not trying to maintain a big spaghetti mess of if/else's all throughout the page